# How to connect to a SpatiaLite database using ogr in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, postgresql, ogr, sqlite

I need to connect to a SQLite/SpatiaLite database to copy data there. I have done the same with PostgreSQL/PostGIS like this:

```
connection_string = "dbname={} user={} password={} host={} port={}".format(
                self.dbname,
                config.get_config_value(dbsettings, "user"),
                config.get_config_value(dbsettings, "password"),
                config.get_config_value(dbsettings, "host"),
                config.get_config_value(dbsettings, "port")
            )
ogr.Open("PG:" + connection_string)
```

I followed instructions [here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html) where it is specified how to connect to PostgreSQL. But [in the SQLite section](http://gdal.org/drv_sqlite.html), there isn't any information on connecting to the database. I suppose there also will be a connection string with a path to the database file instead of **port** and **host** but I need the exact syntax.

I am using Python 3.5.

EDIT:

I need to use ogr.open (not sqlite3.connect) because I store data to the database using CopyLayer (a method of ogr.open) as can be seen here (this is for PsotgreSQL):

```
    dsc_in = ogr.Open(file_name)
    dsc_out = ogr.Open("PG:" + self.target)

    layer = dsc_out.CopyLayer(dsc_in.GetLayer(), identifier,
                              ['OVERWRITE=YES'])
    if layer is None:
        raise Exception("Writing output data to the database failed.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think you need to build a connection string (as opposed to db services) for sqlite connections. This works fine for me:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ds = ogr.Open('spatialite.db')

for i in range(ds.GetLayerCount()):
    print(df.GetLayerByIndex(i).GetName())
```

Comment: side note: please check if your gdal/ogr was compiled with spatialite support (run `ogrinfo --formats` and spatialite should be in the list)

Comment: When I do is like this, ds is None. Any idea what might be causing it or where to look? I am using Linux Bash Shell on Win 10.

Comment: I run the "ogrinfo --formats" command and spatialite is on the list ( SQLite -vector- (rw+v): SQLite / Spatialite)

Comment: the usual suspect in these case if that the file can't be seen. try os.path.isfile('mydirectory/sqlite.db'). It should return True. If it does do ogrinfo on your sqllite file, if the program relevant information its not a program with gdal/ogr

Comment: os.path.isfile('mydirectory/sqlite.db') returns True. When I run ogrinfo testdb.sqlite3, it returns "FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `testdb.sqlite3' with the following drivers." (and then a list of drivers). SQLite is on the list.

Comment: then your spatialite file is not an actual spatialite datafile. ogrinfo tries to open the file with every driver enabled to it and fails. It's not a python, or ogr problem

Answer (score 1):

Python has a native library for working with sqlite, you might be better off using that.

`import sqlite3
sqlite3.connect("path/to/db")`

Comment: I need to use ogr.open. I updated the question so it is clear why. But maybe I am missing something..